# Display the split text of the path if it exists else display nothing

Tags: jquery, arrays, dynamic, split, conditional-statements

I need to display the name and split path of the path entered by a user dynamically.
For that, I had split the path entered by the user and grab only certain part of it. For e.g. if the use enters path as:

/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/abc.jpg
Then I am displaying images/abc.jpg.

However, lets say the user only enters the name and doesn't enter the path, atleast the name should be appened & displayed in that case.

But it throws an error when am trying to do that.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#getData').click(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();
    var newPath = imgPath.match(/images\/.*$/i)[0];
    $('.container').append(
      $('<p>').text(name),
      $('<p>').text(newPath, function(){
        return /^\/images/.test(newPath) ? src :$('#imgPath').val();
      })
    );
    //console.log(slicedPath);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name: <input type="text" id="name">
Image path: <input type="text" id="imgPath">
<div class="container">

</div>
<button id="getData">Click</button>
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in this line

```
var newPath = imgPath.match(/images\/.*$/i)[0];
```

you are trying to run a match with a regex and then select the first result, the [0] position. so when there is no results, you try to get the [0] position when there is none.

just remove that [0] at the end of the line and this will work

```
var newPath = imgPath.match(/images\/.*$/i);
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! By the way, I'd made another mistake using src instead of text in my code where I'm checking for the value.

Comment: cool that you found it, tell me if I can help in anything else

Comment: It works well, but I don't think the return value I've written is correct! Need to change that to ensure it works accurately! Could you help me do that?

Comment: your problem was solved for this, I'd recomend to you to create a new question or if it's simple of course I can try to help, what is wrong with the result?

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution here -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535696/return-the-split-value-if-the-user-had-entered-the-path-else-return-blank/43535759?noredirect=1#comment74123847_43535759