# Return the split value if the user had entered the path else return blank

Tags: jquery, dynamic, split, return, conditional-statements

I need to display the name and split path of the path entered by a user dynamically.
For that, I had split the path entered by the user and grab only certain part of it. For e.g. if the user enters path as:

/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/abc.jpg
Then I am displaying images/abc.jpg.

However, let's say the user only enters the name and doesn't enter the path, at least the name should be applied & displayed in that case.

But it displays 0 everytime I enter a path.
How do I fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#getData').click(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();
    var newPath = imgPath.match(/images\/.*$/i);
    $('.container').append(
      $('<p>').text(name),
      $('<p>').text(function(imgPath){
        return newPath ? imgPath : $('#imgPath').val();
      })
    );
    //console.log(slicedPath);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name: <input type="text" id="name">
Image path: <input type="text" id="imgPath">
<div class="container">

</div>
<button id="getData">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

I've only changed your return statement `return newPath != null ? newPath : imgPath;`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#getData').click(function(){
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var imgPath = $('#imgPath').val();
    var newPath = imgPath.match(/images\/.*$/i);
    $('.container').append(
      $('<p>').text(name),
      $('<p>').text(function(imgPath){
        return newPath != null ? newPath : $('#imgPath').val();
      })
    );
    //console.log(slicedPath);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name: <input type="text" id="name">
Image path: <input type="text" id="imgPath">
<div class="container">

</div>
<button id="getData">Click</button>


/content/mypath/myfolder/about/images/abc.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you, but if the Image path is blank, it is displaying 0; Ideally, it should display blank.

Comment: @Sunny try now. If the image path is black it returns nothing

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :)

Comment: I've asked a similar question in case of JSON, how to get that to work. Could you please help me with that?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537688/return-the-split-path-if-the-json-attribute-exists-else-return-blank